# Unlink page from master

Tags: sharepoint-designer, master-page, xslt-list-view-web-part, aspx

Is there a way to "unlink" a page from the master page? Specifically, what I want to do is have a completely blank page display a SharePoint ListViewWebPart.

Alternatively, if I start by creating a blank page, I cannot seem to add any web parts to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a web part page with out a master page, but that means that you have to put some of the controls from the master page into you page.

Alternative you can create a blank master page and use that.

But the simplest solution is to just hide the parts of the master page you don't want to show using css like this:

```
<style>
.s4-notdlg, #s4-ribbonrow {
    display:none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Yes. I implemented the css you recommended. Works well enough, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out - First create a blank master page, create your page normally and then force that particular page to use the blank master page

Check out [this](http://ianankers.wordpress.com/2011/10/11/create-a-blank-publishing-page-in-sharepoint-2010-for-a-print-view-or-hosting-in-an-iframe/) link for more help.